# Amazon cloudfront Invalidation request python encodign issue

Tags: python, boto, amazon-cloudfront

Sending an invalidation request using python Boto library Cloudfront is receiving an Object Path like this: /p/30100/30151/15198/%2A but I'm sending the file like this: /p/30100/30151/15198/* and cloudfront don't invalidate the folder using the wildcard, ¿Theres a way to send the wildcard without codification?

```
f = self.aws_bucket_name + path + '/*'
files = [f]
conn = CloudFrontConnection(self.aws_access_key, self.aws_secret_access_key)
req = conn.create_invalidation_request(self.aws_cf_distribution_id, files)
print req.status
```

Comment: Got any answer for this?

Comment: I'm sorrry @GagandeepSingh but I could not find an answer about this.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer and implemented on my system. Basically, boto fixed this in their [develop branch](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/b98757fdddd1b2fd75a1008df7be4908f17361b3) and their [latest release](https://github.com/boto/boto/releases) is on May

**Solution** just need to install git develop branch instead.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/boto/boto.git#develop
```

One more thing,

```
f = path + '/*'
```

**Update -** As per comment below, this fix is in place with version 2.43.00+

Comment: As of 2.43.00 this fix is in place.